# Why can't I reference a character in a string that was previously cast to void?

Tags: c

To use pthreads, I used as input a char* that was cast to void* as input. If it's later cast to (char*) it can be printed and used normally ( (char*)var ). However, if one does (char*)var[i], where 'i' will help us reference a character, it doesn't. Why?

e.g. MS says 'expression must be a pointer to a complete object type'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of operator precedence: the cast comes after the subscript operator.

You have to write `((char*)var)[i];`.

Answer (score 2):

The cast, in this case, is lower precedence than the array indexing. Instead, you would have to do something like `*((char *)var + i)`, but the clearest approach is probably to assign it to a temporary:

```
 char *str = var;
 printf("%c", str[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `(char *) &var[i]`, but that simply gets reference from `var[i]`. You can't do `(char *) var[i]` as that actually tries to convert a `char to (char *)`.

Comment: I like your thinking in the second sentence. It explains it clearly. That also explains why Simone's answer works.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `var[0]`, with or without `&`, is wrong, because it expands to `*var`, which attempts to dereference a `void *` pointer. I'm pretty sure the standard doesn't guarantee that, in an expression `&arr[ind]`, the dereference will be optimized out.

Comment: @Chris, even when that optimization, you end up with `(char *) (var + i)`, and arithmetic on void pointers is not permitted.